# expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to RSpec and this error is all new to me. Everything seems routine so I can't seem to debug this issue myself. ERROR: expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0. I'll post my code for clarity.

SUBSCRIBER FACTORY:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :subscriber do
 first_name "Tyler"
 last_name "Durden"
 email "tyler@example.com"
 phone_number "8765555"
end
end
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @comment = Comment.new
 end

 def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.order('updated_at desc').first
  @comment = @subscriber.comments.build(comments_params)
 if @comment.save
  flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
  redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
 else
  render "new"
 end
end

private

def comments_params
 params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink, :subscriber_id)
end
end
```

SPEC:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe SubscribersController do
include Devise::TestHelpers

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:subscriber) }

it "creates a new comment" do
  sign_in(user)
  comment = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment)

  expect { post :create, subscriber: subscriber, comment: comment }.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
end
end
```

ERROR:

```
  Failure/Error: expect { post :create, subscriber: subscriber, comment: comment }.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
   expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/comment_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: please, provide your helpers and controller actual code in question

Comment: I'm on it Thanks for all your help.

Comment: How does your `subscriber` factory look like? Does your `Comment` model have any validators?

Comment: No the model does not have any validators. I'll post that factory

Comment: what happens when you change your controller to raise if the save fails?  So change this "if @comment.save" to "if @comment.save!"  Also if My answer for your last question was correct please mark it as the answer :)

Comment: That didn't work but I marked your answer as correct thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you're showing your comments controller, expecting one of its actions to be hit. However, your test case is actually calling the `create` route of the *Subscriptions* controller.

When, in your test case, you write `describe SubscribersController do`, you are establishing a *scope* for the HTTP requests you make in that block.

So when you call `post :create, subscriber: subscriber, comment: comment`,
it's the Subscriptions controller which is being hit.

In general, in order to debug, you should

1. check that the area of code in question is being called
2. check that values are correct (here, that would mean that the `Comment.create` object is successfully saved.